# SQL Recursive evaluation for each record from separate table (parseJSON)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, recursion, cross-apply

I'm trying to evaluate a JSON response in SQL for each of the records and merge these into one table.

I'm currently using [consuming-json-strings-in-sql-server/](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/consuming-json-strings-in-sql-server/) to parse the json which returns a table-valued function, 
e.g.

```
select *
from parseJSON('{"a":1}');
```

which gives

```
element_id sequenceNo  parent_ID   Object_ID   NAME    StringValue ValueType
    1           0           1       NULL        a                       int
    2           1           NULL    1           -                       object
```

This needs to recurse on each record and merge for each JSON string stored in another table. I'm sure I'm overthinking this again and hoping something simple is around the corner...

As always, any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: [Guidelines for Defining and Using Recursive Common Table Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql#guidelines-for-defining-and-using-recursive-common-table-expressions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is this:

```
select t.*,j.* from yourtable t cross apply parseJSON(t.jsonColumn) j
```

Comment: Thanks, told you I was overthinking it!

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to join the returned property from json and column of a table ?

```
select * from table1 t inner join 
(select * from parseJSON('{"a":1}') where Name = 'a') p
ON t.a = p.Name
```